# Watson Retrieve & Rank Service and IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, retrieve-and-rank

I am new to Watson and want to use Retrieve and Rank Service. Reading the documents so far, I understand that IBM Bluemix provides a Retrieve and Rank Service. 
I am under the impression that IBM Bluemix Retrieve and Rank Service is meant primarily for Developers to develop and test the application as there are limitations on cluster units and size of a unit.
Should I use the same service (I mean the one provided by IBM Bluemix) for production deployment also or there are other options?

Answer (score 1):

Vikram, welcome to Stack Overflow. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow  is to answer technical programming questions. Questions like yours about the capabilities of vendors' offerings are usually voted down or removed.

The Watson Retrieve and Rank Service is intended for customer-facing professionals, such as support staff, contact center agents, field technicians, and other professionals, who must find relevant results quickly from large numbers of documents. It is not primarily a development tool.

If you have follow-up questions please check the [Watson Retrieve and Rank documentation](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/index.shtml#uses) or ask on IBM's [developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html?sort=newest&smartspace=bluemix) forum.

For a better idea of how to use Stack Overflow, check out these tips on [what topics to ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what makes a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you @ralphearle. I will check the documentation again.